# Unknown errors ocuur in front page

Tags: tabularx, minipage, tabularray, front-matter

I am actually using the template from my University, which you can find it attached at the end.

However, I constantly get the errors from the logs.

[image]

It occure ant the last one \end{minipage} line. This 6 errors repeat the same text:

> ...twotitle }~\thesissupervisortwoname
> ~\MakeUppercase {\thesissu...
> l.46 \end{minipage} \hfill \null}
> \
> The control sequence at the end of the top line
> of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
> misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type` I' and the correct
> spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
> and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

I used so many packages.

> \usepackage{array,tabularx,calc}

> \usepackage{tabularray}

And I guess the problem might caused by the conflict from some of these packages.

```
\newgeometry{top=4cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,bottom=4cm,heightrounded}
\begin{titlepage}
\centering
%
{\institutionfont \textbf{\MakeUppercase{\thesisuniversity}} \par}
%
\vspace{\stretch{2}} % changing this number and the others changes the proportion
%
{\divisionfont \textbf{\thesislevel's Degree in \thesiscourse} \par}
%
\vspace{\stretch{3}}
%
\includegraphics[width=50mm]{\thesisuniversitylogo}\\
%
\vspace{\stretch{4}}
%
{\divisionfont \textbf{\thesislevel's Degree Thesis} \par}
%
\vspace{\stretch{3}}
%
{\customtitlefont \textbf{\thesistitle} \par}
%
\vspace{\stretch{10}}
%
\makebox[\textwidth]{\null\hfill\def\arraystretch{2}% % to change the spacing change this number
\begin{minipage}[t]{.375\textwidth}\raggedright
    \begin{adjustbox}{width={\textwidth},totalheight={\textheight},keepaspectratio} % with adjustbox it adapts to the lengths of the names, remove it if you want the same font dimension
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
        \fixednamesfont \textbf{\thesissupervisortext} \\
        \namesfont \xmakefirstuc{\thesissupervisoronetitle}~\thesissupervisoronename~\MakeUppercase{\thesissupervisoronesurname}\\
        \namesfont \xmakefirstuc{\thesissupervisortwotitle}~\thesissupervisortwoname~\MakeUppercase{\thesissupervisortwosurname}\\
        \namesfont \xmakefirstuc{\thesissupervisorthreetitle}~\thesissupervisorthreename~\MakeUppercase{\thesissupervisorthreesurname}
    \end{tabular}
    \end{adjustbox}
\end{minipage}
%
\hfill
%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.375\textwidth}\raggedleft
\begin{adjustbox}{width={\textwidth},totalheight={\textheight},keepaspectratio} % with adjustbox it adapts to the lengths of the names, remove it if you want the same font dimension
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
    \fixednamesfont \textbf{\thesiscandidatetext} \\
    \namesfont \thesiscandidatename~\MakeUppercase{\thesiscandidatesurname}
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{minipage} \hfill \null} \\
%
\vspace{\stretch{5}}
%
{\footfont \textbf{\thesisdate} \par}
%
\end{titlepage}

\restoregeometry
```

Comment: Please don't just show code fragments. Make a copy of your document, then keep removing stuff as long as the error is still there. This should give you a small test file which allows us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Probably something like `\thesissupervisortwoname` is undefined. But without more information about the actual document class and with a lot of your document missing and with the errormessage not shared literally (including line breaks) it is difficult to say. Did you define your Supervisor #2?